# Print lines containing exact strings in several columns awk ubuntu

Tags: awk

How do I print out the lines in awk, that contain certain strings in certain columns e.g. str = "x" in first column and str = "y" in second column?

```
x  y
d  y
f  o
x  o
```

So that in this example only the first line is printed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the first few pages of the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '$1=="x" && $2=="y"' file
x  y
```

#### How it works

awk statements consist of conditions and actions.  In this case, the condition is that the first column equals `x` and the second column equals `y`.  Since we don't specify an action, awk performs its default action which is to print the line.

In other words, `$1=="x" && $2=="y"` is a condition.  `&&` means logical-and.  Thus, this condition is true only if both `$1=="x"` and `$2=="y"` are true.